Euclid’s “Elements” Redux Callahan's Problem 3
I'm working through Euclid's “Elements” Redux by Callahan (The 13 June 2024 edition), but I have a problem demonstrating the exercise. This time is one on page 107, specifically the number 7. The problem says:


In Fig. 1.5.25: if $EG$ is constructed, prove that $ EG^2= AC^2+ 4·BC^2.$



We could see that $△COB\cong△BRE$. So, by the Pythagorean Theorem, $$GE^2=(AB+CO)^2+(AB+OB)^2.$$
Simplifying, I get $$GE^2=AC^2+4BC^2+AB^2+2AB(CO).$$
I'm using the fact that $BC=AB(BO)$ and $CO=AO(OB)$
I don't know if I'm committing an error. So please, tell me what's my error.

I think there is a typo in the  the original book. The equality relation should actually be $EF^2 = AC^2 + 4\cdot BC^2$

That is right! Thanks man. I was all day checking what was my error.

@tToE should post that as an answer and OP should accept so that this question doesn't remain on the "unanswered" list.

As already mentioned in the comment, I think there is a typo in the original book.
The equality relation should actually be
$$
\overline{EF}^2 = \overline{AC}^2 + 4\cdot \overline{BC}^2
$$
The proof of this equality relation can be further deduced easily following the OP's process:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\overline{EF}^2 & = \overline{CO}^2 + \left(\overline{AB} + \overline{OB}\right)^2\\
&= \overline{CO}^2 + \overline{OB}^2 + \overline{AB}^2 + 2\overline{AB}\cdot\overline{OB}\\
& = \overline{BC}^2 + \left( \overline{AC}^2 +  \overline{BC}^2 \right) + 2\overline{BC}^2 \\
& = \overline{AC}^2 + 4\cdot \overline{BC}^2
\end{aligned}
$$
